# mkdir does not create new folder in php (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, mkdir

I am using CodeIgniter,
When I click submit I get redirected to a control which makes a photo album.
When that's done I need to create a map in `images/albums/` so I can add photo's in there later on.

http://myproject/application/images/albums/feafa
my code:

```
$path = base_url() . APPPATH . 'images/albums/'. $albums->Album_en;

if(!file_exists($path))
{
   mkdir($path);
}
```

Comment: And the question is ?

Comment: check this if (!is_dir('base_url() . APPPATH . 'images/albums/'')) { mkdir($path, 0777, TRUE); }

Comment: Do the parent folders exist? If not, you may want to set the recursive flag on the mkdir() call.

Comment: does the web server have permission to create files/folders in the location you are trying?  Can you create a file in the folder you are looking to create a folder in?

Comment: @Astro No one should be setting anything to 0777 because of insecurities.

Comment: @Astro When executing this code he gave true(echo "done")  $path = base_url() . APPPATH . 'images/albums/'. $albums->Album_en;

        
        if (!is_dir(base_url() . APPPATH . 'images/albums/')) 
        { 
            mkdir($path, 0777, TRUE); 
            echo "done";
        }

Comment: @gabe3886 when creating the folder manually, I can

Comment: @SdR what are yo saying.. sorry i couldnt understand

Comment: @gabe3886 , that the is_dir turned out true, the problem was that base_url() does not return an absolute link.

Comment: use absolute path instead of base_url()

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
 $path = realpath(APPPATH . 'images/albums/'. $albums->Album_en);
```

instead of

```
$path = base_url() . APPPATH . 'images/albums/'. $albums->Album_en;
```

The base_url() is irrelevant as mkdir asks for the directory path(ABSOLUTE PATH)